# Installation of jbpm for eclipse mars

Tags: software-installation

I want to install the jbpm but I dont' found a tutoriel about this on ubuntu 15.04.
Please what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In the Eclipse Mars JEE distribution is a BPMN2 available which provides a metamodel implementation based on the Business Process Model and Notation (BPMN) 2.0 OMG specification.

[image]

But ... I suspect you will need the full jBPM suite.
The full suite of jBPM is not available as a plugin in Eclipse Mars.
You have to download the installer [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jbpm/files/jBPM%206/) to install the whole distribution. More information [here](http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.3/userguide/ch01.html).